# Should SD card be removable with little pressure?

Tags: hardware, sd-card

I;'ve just purchased a raspberry pi b+ and the Noobs card. I've inserted the card into the slot on device and heard it click. But I'm able to remove the card easily without re-pressing the card into its slot (which ejects the card). Is this is expected or should the card be locked into place until pressure is applied to eject it ?

Comment: that is how it is designed on the B+

Comment: There's no spring eject on the plain B; you have to pull it out gently.  You also have to make sure you push it back in all the way ;)

Comment: @goldilocks True, but that was a plain SD card, not a microSD ;)

Comment: Strange! On my B+, the microSD card is locked - I do have to press it into the slot in order to release it.

Comment: @KlausWarzecha Ah!  Well, perhaps it is supposed to lock in place then (but no big deal if it doesn't, I think).